# Unity 3D C# Watson Visual Recognition Parsing Data

Tags: unity-game-engine, ibm-watson

I am trying to figure out how to parse the data returned during a response from the Visual Recognition service

```
  [07/05/2018 20:39:40][ExampleVisualRecognition.OnClassifyPost()][DEBUG] 
  {"images":[{"classifiers": 
  [{"classifier_id":"Shapes_925471689","name":"Shapes","classes": 
  [{"class":"Square","score":0.787}]},
```

I know that customData["json"].ToString()) prints this output, and it a dictionary object but how would I extract specific data from the dictionary/Json such as "class" value "Square" ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36239705/serialize-and-deserialize-json-and-json-array-in-unity

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the ClassifiedImages object to get those values.

```
private void OnClassify(ClassifiedImages classify, Dictionary<string, object> customData)
{
    Log.Debug("Classification result", "class: {0}", classify.classifiers[0] );
}
```

Comment: thanks taj. I re-parsed the data using simple JSON, though I realise now that this was not needed